Where can i use solidity to deploy apps on Solana?
I need to know whether I can use Solidity to deploy apps on Solana.

Yes, it is possible to write your contracts using Solidity via the Solang project,
Check out the docs here: https://solang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/targets/solana.html
